# Express app with MSSQL created with CLI not connecting correctly to database

Tags: node.js, sql-server, express

I have a problem with an app I created using the Express CLI. It's important to note that I'm using `mssql` for my connection to the database.

When I use `npm start`, the app starts without a problem, but when I run `node ./bin/www`, the app starts, but it fails to connect to the database. I'm getting the error `"Invalid server: undefined"`.

When I check my `package.json` file, I have:

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www",
    "debug": "set DEBUG=myapp:* & npm start",
    "nodemon": "npx nodemon"
  },
```

As far as I understand, it should be exactly the same to run `npm start` than `node ./bin/www`, but for some reason it is not.

As to why this is a problem, I want to leave the app running using `pm2`, and so, I need to be able to run the app from a file, and not from a command.

This is my `www` file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */

var app = require('../app');
var debug = require('debug')('mtloops-web-api:server');
var http = require('http');

/**
 * Get port from environment and store in Express.
 */

var port = normalizePort('3543');
app.set('port', port);

/**
 * Create HTTP server.
 */

var server = http.createServer(app);

/**
 * Listen on provided port, on all network interfaces.
 */

server.listen(port);
server.on('error', onError);
server.on('listening', onListening);

/**
 * Normalize a port into a number, string, or false.
 */

function normalizePort(val) {
  var port = parseInt(val, 10);

  if (isNaN(port)) {
    // named pipe
    return val;
  }

  if (port >= 0) {
    // port number
    return port;
  }

  return false;
}

/**
 * Event listener for HTTP server "error" event.
 */

function onError(error) {
  if (error.syscall !== 'listen') {
    throw error;
  }

  var bind = typeof port === 'string'
    ? 'Pipe ' + port
    : 'Port ' + port;

  // handle specific listen errors with friendly messages
  switch (error.code) {
    case 'EACCES':
      console.error(bind + ' requires elevated privileges');
      process.exit(1);
      break;
    case 'EADDRINUSE':
      console.error(bind + ' is already in use');
      process.exit(1);
      break;
    default:
      throw error;
  }
}

/**
 * Event listener for HTTP server "listening" event.
 */

function onListening() {
  var addr = server.address();
  var bind = typeof addr === 'string'
    ? 'pipe ' + addr
    : 'port ' + addr.port;
  debug('Listening on ' + bind);
}
```

This is my database connection file:

```
const sql = require('mssql')
// const path = require('path')
require('dotenv').config()

var config = {
  user: process.env.DBUSERNAME,
  password: process.env.DBPASSWORD,
  server: process.env.HOST,
  database: process.env.DATABASE,
  connectionTimeout: 300000,
  requestTimeout: 300000,
  pool: {
    idleTimeoutMillis: 300000,
    max: 100
  },
  options: {
    encrypt: false
  }
}

async function sp (procedure, params) {
  const toReturn = await new sql.ConnectionPool(config).connect().then(pool => {
    const request = pool.request()
    Object.keys(params).forEach(key => {
      if (isNaN(params[key])) {
        request.input(key, sql.VarChar(8), params[key])
      } else {
        var numeric = parseInt(params[key])
        request.input(key, sql.Int, numeric <= 0 ? -1 : numeric)
      }
    })
    return request.execute(procedure)
  }).catch(error => {
    throw error.message
  })
  return toReturn
}

module.exports = {
  sp
}
```

Comment: Please post the code of www

Comment: Added it as an edit. The `www` is the standard one created by the express CLI tho, I only changed the port (to 3543).

Comment: It does not have any code to connect to a database

Comment: I know, the connection doesn't run in the `www`. But for some reason, even tho the `npm start` and `node www` should do exactly the same, they don't

Comment: Added the file in which I create the connection to the database, but I don't think that's where the problem is